# Getting blank SyntaxError on the last line

Tags: python, python-3.x, twython

I'm a beginner to programming, and i'm trying to write this twitter bot using Twython as an exercise to learn Python. I've started getting this SyntaxError on the last line:

```
     ~/tweetbot $ python tweet_test.py
File "tweet_test.py", line 32

               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've searched for the problem, and it seems to normally be related either to leaving parenthesis open, or Python expecting some more code. I tried different things I found, like ending with sys.exit(), but I seem to always get the SyntaxError.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from twython import Twython, TwythonError


apiKey = 'letters and numbers'
apiSecret = 'letters and numbers'
accessToken = 'letters and numbers'
accessTokenSecret = 'letters and numbers'

twitter = Twython(apiKey, apiSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)


try:
    searchResult = twitter.search(q='searchTerm',lang='es',result_type='recent',count='3')
    for tweet in searchResult['statuses']:
        tweeted = open('answered').readlines()
        if tweet['id_str'] in tweeted:
            print '1 tweet is already answered'
        else:
            print 'Tweet from @%s Date: %s' % (tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8'), tweet['created_at'])
            print tweet['text'].encode('utf-8'), '\n'

            twitter.update_status(status=message, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet['id_str'])
            message = 'tweetReply'
            print "Tweeted: " + message

            answeredTweet = '"' + tweet['id_str'] + '"\n'
            f = open('answered', 'w')
            f.write(answeredTweet)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never provide an [`except:` or `finally:` block for your `try:` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement). It is **not** optional.

If you didn't actually want to use an exception handler, just remove the `try:` and un-indent the whole block.

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed the problem.